# How to cancel Auto-Renewable Subscription by using Test User

Tags: subscription

Apple iTuneConnect Document said that "Do not enter your test account information in the Store settings panel. Doing so may invalidate
your test account."

If I need to test verified transcation again, how to re-subscribe it again? 
How to test auto-renewal subscription expiration?

Thanks

Comment: This was a perfectly valid question.

Comment: it was actually.... anyways, i'm not sure about canceling, but the docs state somewhere, that the test user subscription period is quite smaller (e.g. 1 week - 3 min, 1 month - 5 mins .... 1 year - 1 hour), and that after five renew(s) it will auto cancel it's self... Hope this helps...

Comment: This is what they mean by that: They want you to clear your normal Apple account from within the Settings app. That way, when you try a test purchase, it will prompt you for an account and you can enter your test account at that point.  Just don't enter your test credentials into the Settings app or the App Store app, cause you don't want to make it the default account for your whole device.

Comment: This is indeed a valid question and it's a shame it was closed. Apple's documentation around sandboxing (esp with subscriptions) is shoddy at best.